# No High Availability on oVirt Self-Hosted Engine Cluster

Tags: redhat, cluster, high-availability, ovirt

I'm trying out oVirt's cluster HA for virtual machines (specifically Red Hat Virtualization 4.0, but I'm not having any luck getting the Manager VM to be highly available. The steps I took are essentially:

1. Set up node1 and run hosted-engine script with iscsi storage.
2. Set up node2 and continue hosted-engine script with same iscsi path.
3. Add cluster/master storage to Manager VM and have the datacenter running.

I've followed the documentation provided by Red Hat which says HA should be enabled at this point. The problem is that when I go to the Manager VM settings through its web portal, it states "VM cannot be set highly available when hosted engine is used".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A power fencing device is required for any High Availability to work. IPMI / iDRAC can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK hosted engine is made HA out of the box, so you can't do anything about it from the UI itself. The UI settings are for regular VMs

Comment: That's what it seemed like, but when I shut down one of the nodes, the manager did not start on the second node automatically. Perhaps a power fencing device for power management is required for HA to work on the manager?

Comment: Of course, without fencing enabled, you have no SBA, and no HA will work, neither for the engine nor for the VMs

Comment: I ended up figuring that out the same day I posted the comment. Either I missed it in the documentation, or it's just not there listed as a requirement. Thank you.